# Flutter Doctor Scanning for devices takes a very long time

Tags: android-studio, flutter

I'm encountering a problem in windows flutter installation. if I run flutter doctor -v it stuck on the scanning of devices. I've already uninstalled reinstalled flutter and android studio but still facing the same issue. I've tried every solution I could find on the web but to no avail. I am trying to make this run the whole day and still unsuccessful. Thanks for the help.

Here's a screenshot of the Scanning of devices is taking a long time.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This might happen if you have any emulator process running in the background.

Try rebooting the system.

Comment: oh. I will edit the answer. Thank you. I will keep that in mind.

Comment: Rebooted and it worked.